# Text Field Value is not stored in string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

In my app, I have many text field & at last there is take photo button. But when i return from selecting photo,the inserted textfield Value is shown me blank.

I try with storing the text field value into string when click to photo button. and when i return from that i set the string value to text fied But it shown me Bad excess.

Help me!!

```
-(void)ViewWillAppear
{
     if (clkph) {
             txtdate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phdate];
             NSLog(@"%@",txtdate.text);
             txttime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phtime];
             NSLog(@"%@",txttime.text);
         }
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    clkph=YES;
    phdate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtdate];
    NSLog(@"%@",phdate);
    phtime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txttime];
    NSLog(@"%@",phtime);
}
```

Comment: We can't help you without any piece of code. Please add some snippets, so we can check what you are doing!

Comment: check phdate and phtime  is nsstring has value

Comment: phdate & phtime by Nslog is:<UITextField: 0x6b5ae60; frame = (161 12; 150 31); text = '14-Sep-2012'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6b5af80>>
2012-09-14 11:11:36.503 CarAccidentApp[722:207] <UITextField: 0x6b5ce20; frame = (161 59; 150 31); text = '11:11 AM'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6b5cf40>>

Comment: @piyush no, `phdate` is **NOT** a string. It is a `UITextField`. And make sure that they still exist after you return to that screen(they are not `nil`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this as i assume phdate and  phtime as UITextField:

```
if (clkph) {
         txtdate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phdate];
          NSLog(@"%@",txtdate.text);
          txttime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phtime];
          NSLog(@"%@",txttime.text);
     }

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

  clkph=YES;
  phdate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtdate.text];
  [phdate retain];
  NSLog(@"%@",phdate);
  phtime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txttime.text];
  [phtime retain];
  NSLog(@"%@",phtime);
}
```

Comment: phdate is string so we can't write phdate.text

Comment: yes, according to his logs(written in comments), `phdate` and `phtime` are `UITextField`s. Upvote

Comment: @piyush you should really learn to give feedback. From your question and comments I understood (almost) nothing. What doesn't work? What are the errors? Where do they occur? Are you sure that `txtdate` and `txttime` are not `nil`? Etc., etc., etc....

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if (clkph) {
     NSString* txtdate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phdate];
     NSLog(@"%@",txtdate);
     NSString* txttime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phtime];
     NSLog(@"%@",txttime);
 }
```

Comment: ya but ,when i try to set nsstring *txtdate to textfield value it has empty text with all other property of text field like caLayer,frame,